# Error in BeginStartup CollaborationPlatform using ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings

Tags: sql, .net, exception, ucma, lync-server-2010

I am trying to create an ApplicationEndpoint by first creating and establishing the CollaborationPlatform using  ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings, when i execute:

`ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings settings = new ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings("MYAPP", _appID);
_collabPlatform = new CollaborationPlatform(settings);
_collabPlatform.BeginStartup(EndPlatformStartup, _collabPlatform);`

in `EndPlatformStartup` method while executing `collabPlatform.EndStartup(ar);` i get an error

`ProvisioningFailureException:
One or more values in the configured settings are invalid or unusable. Check inner exception and logs for more details.
The settings wrapper failed to initialize.
Unable to find  the Sqld database: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)`

Comment: Not 100% about this as the exception appears to be coming from your Lync Server but could you confirm that you have run the "Lync Server 201x bootstrapper prerequisites Installer Package" on the application server?

Comment: yes i have run Lync Server 2013 bootstrapper prerequisites Installer Package

Comment: I assumed that the application pool, trusted application and trusted application endpoints have been configured on the Lync Server is this right?

Comment: yes they have been configured, but the cms replication UpToDate is False, i am not able to replicate cms for the ApplicationPool

Comment: Is replication enabled on the application pool.  To verify use get-csTrustedApplicationPool and check ReplicationRequired is true.  Hang in there I've seen this before just trying to remember the cause.

Comment: yes, i get ReplicationRequired as true, when i run Get-CsManagementStroeReplicationStatus i get this                     `UpToDate           : True
ReplicaFqdn        : MyLyncServer.Machine.Domain
LastStatusReport   : 14-08-2014 11:21:17
LastUpdateCreation : 14-08-2014 11:21:16
ProductVersion     : 5.0.8308.0

UpToDate           : False
ReplicaFqdn        : FakeHost.MyLynServer.Machine.Domain
LastStatusReport   :
LastUpdateCreation : 14-08-2014 11:21:16
ProductVersion     :`

Comment: Ok I think we are going to need to try some logging.  Could you set up a log on XDS_Replica_Replicator and run Invoke-CSManagementStoreReplication from your front end server and then check the log for any errors against that component.

Comment: Tried logging,didnt get any error `TL_INFO(TF_COMPONENT) (XDS_Replica_Replicator,PerReplicaTaskManagerT<>.HandleTaskError:perreplicataskmanager.cs(234))
(00000000009A2F17)Task encountered an error: [ReplicaTaskContainer<FileDistributeTask>{FileDistributeTask{E:\RtcReplicaRoot\xds-replica\from-master\data.zip, E:\RtcReplicaRoot\xds-replica\working\replication\from-master\data.zip, Access failed. (E:\RtcReplicaRoot\xds-replica\from-master\data.zip)}, FileDistributeTask{E:\RtcReplicaRoot\xds-replica\from-master\data.zip, E:\RtcReplicaRoot\xds-replica\working\replication\from-master\data.zip, }}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer/Error,
i was trying to run the application from Windows 7 PC which apparently is not supported for [Auto Provisioned Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466090%28v=office.15%29.aspx) , so now i build the application on my Win7 PC and then execute it on the Lync Server.